# Does using dark corn syrup instead of light affect the white color I usually get making fondant?

Tags: cake, corn, decorating, fondant

[The recipe](http://www.yummly.com/recipe/Rolled-Buttercream-Fondant-Allrecipes?columns=4&position=1%2F60) calls for light corn syrup but I couldn't find light corn syrup and would like to use dark instead. Does it affect the color I get at the end (before adding icing colors)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will make it darker and more brown than white. It may also affect any colours you add, adding a slight brown tinge to them.